# Vb.Net - Fetch from DateParam field and then concatenate with other date field

Tags: vb.net

Struggling to write code for this:

Field in Database has this value : 1899-12-30 04:00:00.000

and I want it to return to 2013-07-23 04:00:00.000

so fetched time from database field and then concatenated with today's date.

can someone please help.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

In short:  `Date.Today.Add(oldDate.TimeOfDay)`

Presuming SQL-Server:

```
Dim result As Date
Const sql = "SELECT TOP 1 DateCol FROM dbo.TableName WHERE SomeColumn=@SomeParameter;"
Using con = New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
    Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SomeParameter", yourVariable)
        con.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If reader.Read() Then
                Dim oldDate = reader.GetDateTime(0)
                result = Date.Today.Add(oldDate.TimeOfDay)
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```